# C++' "do ... while" loop equivalent in Mathematica

Tags: functions, function-construction, procedural-programming

Have I missed something or is there no built-in which mimics the behaviour of [*do ... while* loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_do_while_loop.htm)?

I am looking for a construct that evaluates `procedure` **once** and then repeatedly evaluates it while `test` is not fulfilled.

I'm ended up using:

```
While[procedure; test, {}]
```

But clearly the second argument is redundant, so I have a feeling that I'm missing something. Maybe not, but I just want to be sure :)

Comment: `While[(procedure;test)]` - parens. optional, makes it clear I think...

Comment: Not sure how a compound statement is abuse...first example under *scope* in the docs does it in compact form.

Comment: @rasher Agree, abuse is not a good word. I mean, docs say first arg is a *test* which may be missleading and the example you are referring to is ok but formed in easy-to-overlook way. Especially for new users. I think it could be an useful topic for future visitors.

Comment: LOL - I was puzzled why "@" was not working, just noticed you were the OP. I think you're just messing with us ;-}.

Comment: @rasher :D no I'm not. When I was starting to learn MMA I was digging through docs quite alot (*wasn't aware of M.SE*). But documentation has not lead me to the answer, because of the issues I've mentioned above. I figured it out but had a feeling that it is not the way it should be done in MMA.

Comment: @rasher To the conclusion: I don't think there should be a separate function. My goal is to show to *future beginners* :), who may have doubts similar to mine in the past, that this is the way.

Comment: Sorry Kuba, but I'm trying to be even-handed here and this is pretty directly found in the documentation.  Closed. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Don't be sorry :P I can agree because it is common thing that I'm missreading things that are obvious for others. This topic was meant to be for such people like me, in terms of docs interpretation, if there are any :p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ha! maybe it is simple mistake but it is my mostly viewed question :P I'm not the only one :) unless it's because of someone posted it on 9gag or sth for fun ;P

Comment: Kuba, that's interesting.  I suppose it may be a popular search.  You just got my +1 for that. :-)  Still I think I'll leave this closed unless someone comments that they have something special to post.

Comment: `DoWhile` exists as a function and as a [macro rule](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115884/18476) in ``GeneralUtilities` ``.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While `While[procedure; test]` works, it *looks* very similar to `While[test, procedure]`.  The only difference is `;` vs `,`.  `While` is not the most commonly used construct, so when used like this there's a high chance of misunderstanding/misreading.

If readability/reliability is a concern (for example a collaboratively developed published package), I'd use the longer but clearer

```
While[True,
  procedure;
  If[Not[test], Break[]]
]
```

The only argument here is readability and "defensive programming" (extra effort to avoid accidental problems).  Readability is subjective.  If you are the only person who writes/reads the code and you get used to this use of `While` (and thus always pay special attention to the `,` vs `;`) then this argument doesn't apply.

Answer (score 13):

Version 13.1 introduced the function [`Until`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Until.html)

> **Until**[*test*,*body*] evaluates *body* and then *test*, repetitively, until *test* first gives **True**.

Answer (score 7):

Why not write your own and place it in your init.m file?

```
SetAttributes[DoWhile, HoldAll];

DoWhile[procedure_, test_] := While[procedure; test]
```

Comment: One point against is that the code with it posted on SE requires explanation :)

Comment: @Kuba what do you mean? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: If I put that in my init file and then post the answer here, using this function, I will have to add definition :)

Comment: Oh haha, got it!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to write your own:

```
SetAttributes[doWhile, HoldAll];    
doWhile[expr_, test_] := CompoundExpression[expr, While[test, expr]]
```

Or just:

```
doWhile[expr_, test_] := (expr; While[test, expr])
```