# plot randomly oriented lines

Tags: graphics3d

I want to create the following graphic:

A set of line-elements are randomly oriented in planes parallel to xy-plane.
In addition, on each plane the drawed line-elements should not cross each other.
Also, the magnitude of these line-elements is not constant.

How is it possible to create the figure?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The hard part will be the non-crossing thing.

Comment: For a start, try `Line[{{RandomReal[],RandomReal[],z},{RandomReal[],RandomReal[],z}}]/.z->RandomReal[]`

Comment: @YvesKlett non-crossing appears to be trivial enough. `line1=RegionMember[Line[{{...}}],{x,y,z}];line2=RegionMember...;` then `Reduce[line1&&line2]`. If it comes up with a solution, then they cross.

Comment: Do you want the the planes to be discrete,for example random integer `z`s? Because with float random numbers of @LLlAMnYP 's comment, it's highly, highly unlikely that two lines will end up in the same plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @egwenesedai. Yes, if for instance, 100 lines are drawed in total I want several of them to appear on the same plane.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP nice - how would that fare performance-wise for many lines that need to be compared?

Comment: @YvesKlett: What I have tried so far have been done with ParametricPlot3D. But nothing sophisticated. And certainly no truly randomly:-)!

Comment: @YvesKlett actually the performance is surprisingly good even without coding an analytical approach: `lines = Partition[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}],2]; Solve[RegionMember[Line[First@lines], {x, y}] && 
     RegionMember[Line[#], {x, y}]] & /@ Rest[lines] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: I guess we are close. So, how will be the final code?

Comment: @dimitris If you would care to define the problem as specifically as possible, that is, including constraints on coordinates, at what z coordinates you would like the lines to lie, how many lines per plane, anything of that sort that comes to your mind, I'd give it a shot.

Comment: If you have the time, give it a try. I don't have something particular in my mind. I just want to reproduce a fiber-reinforced composite with fibers randomly oriented in planes parallel to xy-plane. The requirements are different length of these line elements, different orientation and certainly non-crossing which is a physical requirement. If you don't have the time, for me it suffices the combination of the previous codes.

Comment: For instance: How it will be used the output of `lines = Partition[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}],2]; Solve[RegionMember[Line[First@lines], {x, y}] && RegionMember[Line[#], {x, y}]] & /@ Rest[lines]`

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/13714#13714) for a way to check line intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but it, perhaps, deals with the hardest part: constructing a set of finite lines lying all in one plane, but not intersecting each other.

```
appendLine[list_Symbol] := (list = RandomReal[10, {1, 2, 2}])
appendLine[list_List] := Module[{newline, test = True},
  For[newline = RandomReal[10, {2, 2}], test, 
   test = ! 
     AllTrue[Solve[
         RegionMember[Line[newline], {x, y}] && 
          RegionMember[Line[#], {x, y}]] & /@ list, Length@# == 0 &], 
   newline = RandomReal[10, {2, 2}]];
  Append[list, newline]]
```

Run `list = appendLine[list]` `n` times to get `n` lines:

```
Do[list = appendLine[list], {n, 20}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.099410, Null} *) <- (* quite slow for only 20 lines, unfortunately *)
```

Display:

```
Graphics[Line /@ list]
```

> [image: 20lines]

It's a cool model system to study, how depending on initial conditions, for example, all lines mostly orient themselves along a specific direction.

PS - a subsequent addition of 20 lines took 26 seconds, and the next line took another 1.4. Makes sense, as each new random line is more and more likely to intersect the previous ones, so more and more attempts to generate a new line need to be made, until one comes up that fits.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the results. `Graphics[Line /@ list]` results in one line. `Graphics[Line /@ line]` results in two lines even modifying n.

Comment: Crap, typo. `line->list` of course. Will fix

Comment: @dimitris now it should work

Comment: `For[]`, huh? I'd probably have used `While[]` instead; also, you might be interested in the undocumented function for checking line intersections.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. the `FindIntersections` function is undoubtedly pure win :) Maybe I'll get round to updating my answer later. As for `For` or `While` - I don't know, can it really make a difference with an implementation like this? Admittedly, `While` is cleaner. What I was looking for, however, is a `repeat-until` construct.

Comment: I was actually alluding to `IntersectQ[]`, but I'm told these goodies are now in a different context. With respect to looping, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44224)? (All that's needed is to flip the polarity of the termination criterion.)

Comment: No, flipping the polarity is not necessary, as the docs show, all thats needed is the replacement of `<` with `<=` or post-increment to pre-increment and so on. But I generally don't use looping constructs often, so this was something new to learn for me.

Comment: Oh right; for some reason I had thought you were doing "repeat-until". Got confused there… :)

Comment: Yeah, I was *looking* for a repeat-until, but had to do otherwise.