# How can I do a Do While loop

Tags: programming

Many languages have a [Do While loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop), how can I do one in Mathematica ?

Comment: [Reminds me...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6115547#6115547)

Comment: @J.M. Mr. Wizard deleted it... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44224/5478

Comment: @Kuba, hmm, I'd vote to undelete if my powers weren't unilateral. Why not cast an undelete vote, and hope others do so as well? (That will have the unfortunate effect of making this a dupe, tho.)

Comment: @J.M. can't vote to undelete, it was deleted by moderator.

Comment: Alright I set this one as a dupe. If anyone thinks the other thread should be reopened, cast your vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some basic meta programming it's possible to do it.

```
SetAttributes[DoWhile,HoldAll];
DoWhile[expr_,condition_]:=
    While[True,
        expr;

        If[! condition,
            Break[];
        ];
    ];
```

For example

```
i=0
DoWhile[i++,i<0] (*i=1*)

i=-2
DoWhile[i++,i<0] (*i=0*)
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done much easier by putting the body of the loop into the test, like so:

```
While[body;test]
```

For example:

```
While[False,Print["Evaluated body"]]
```

gives no output, whereas

```
While[Print["Evaluated body"];False]
(* Evaluated body *)
```

does.

PS: The documentation for `While` presents my approach as the first example under "Scope" and @faysou's approach under "Generalizations and extensions".

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this approach. I wrote another function as it makes it easier for me to explicitely see a DoWhile as an  abstraction of a concept, plus I think it's a neat and simple illustration of metaprogramming.